# Another word for the source or origin of a derivative

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means the same as the source or origin when generally referring to derivation (the process) or a derivative (the end result)?

Specifically one that would be textually similar to derive/derivation/derivative.

ex. "Derivation of [the source] produces 5 derivatives".

Comment: What's wrong with just using "source"?

Comment: Considering the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=derive) of *derive*, the word *source* is appropriate even though it isn't "textually similar".

Comment: Integral? I don't think there's a word textually similar.

Comment: Loosely speaking, *derivation from [cognates](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cognate) produces derivatives*.

Comment: I'm distracted by the sentence in general. Isn't it obvious that derivation produces derivatives? And why would you want a form of *derive* (is that what you mean by "textually similar"?) as the noun object there? I'm not trying to be obtuse; I just don't understand your goal here. :)

Comment: @TimWard - I'ts a terrible example, but the single-word-request tag said one was needed. I am just curious if there is a word following the same textual pattern. If the answer is "no" that is fine.

Comment: Well, in this case, then the answer is no. I'm fairly certain you won't find a term that is 'textually similar' to *derive* in this context (meaning 'source'), because the word *derive* itself means 'flow from', this same 'flow' as a English *river*, which shares its root origin. You could make a stretch of a connection and use the term *fundamental*, which shares a root origin with *fount*, which is contextually related to *river*. :)

Comment: Careful how you use *derivative*. It has acquired a very specific meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might completely off the mark, but how about "the original"?

Comment: +1 This surely works in copyright which concerns original works and derivative works.

Comment: "original" is not textually similar to "derive", but it is to "origin" or "originate".

Comment: A textually similar word to "derive" with that meaning probably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

"Derivation of **the *underlying* (product)** produces derivatives".